# Authenticate Google Accounts in Google App Engine/Run Code under different User Context - Java Servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I would like to do is to authenticate into Google Accounts using a Username and Password.

Basically,

[Authenticate User Context - Log in Pro grammatically into Google Accounts inside a Java Servlet]

```
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
            [Access Data Store based on Google Account]
```

[Resolve the User Context]

Please help. I would really appreciate it. Can we perform this using UrlFetch ...? I tried remote-api in Google SDK 1.6.1 and there are some issues, the Code in Google Help does not work.

java.io.IOException: can't get appId from remote api; status code = 404
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:313)

I tried as per http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to include

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in your web.xml